# How to evaluate variable with space in a tidyverse function?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, rlang

I am having trouble using variable with a space in a function (terrible idea I know).
The idea here is that I am using a statistical function from rstatix, which is using tidyverse non standard evaluation. Using sym and !!, I am able to make it read the appriate column. However, when the variable has a space, I do not know how to make it work with dplyr NSE.

I added a condition where quantvar is surrounded by backticks if the variable has a space, which allows it to be read by formula and subsequently any statistical test requiring the formula.

The issue comes from the shapiro testing using tidyverse NSE.
Ideally I want to combine the two ways of writing to make the code flexible.

Practically I can just use non NSE functions, or just change my initial data (which I think I'll do).

```r
library(rstatix)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'rstatix'
#> L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(glue)
#> Warning: le package 'glue' a été compilé avec la version R 4.1.3
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: le package 'ggplot2' a été compilé avec la version R 4.1.3
#> Warning: le package 'dplyr' a été compilé avec la version R 4.1.3
make_kruskal_test <-
  function(data, quantvar, groupvar) {
    if (str_detect(quantvar, " ") == TRUE) {
      quantvar <- glue("`{quantvar}`")
    }
    formula_expression <- formula(glue("{quantvar} ~ {groupvar}"))
    bartlett <- bartlett.test(formula_expression, data) %>% print()
    shapiro <- shapiro_test(data, !!sym(quantvar)) %>% print()
  }
data <- tibble("var_snake" = c(1:5), "var space" = 2, "group_var" = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 4))
make_kruskal_test(data, "var_snake", "group_var")
#> 
#>  Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances
#> 
#> data:  var_snake by group_var
#> Bartlett's K-squared = 0.10525, df = 1, p-value = 0.7456
#> 
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   variable  statistic     p
#>   <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 var_snake     0.987 0.967
make_kruskal_test(data, "var space", "group_var")
#> 
#>  Bartlett test of homogeneity of variances
#> 
#> data:  var space by group_var
#> Bartlett's K-squared = NaN, df = 1, p-value = NA
#> Error in `select()`:
#> ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Column `\`\`var space\`\`` doesn't exist.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: would you be okay to use `clean_names` on the dataset instead of having unusual column names i.e. with spaces etc.  It is an issue in `shapiro_test`

Comment: I guess that's the simplest answer. 
Now that you mention it, I tried testing with `dplyr::arrange` and it also doesn't work.

But it does when just pasting `quantvar` without any `!!sym(quantvar)`. But you're right that doing the same with `shapiro_test` makes it look for `quantvar` and not its symbol.

So essentially if I want to do it with dplyr functions, I need to find a way to remove `!!sym` when using variables with space.

Looks like it's way too dumb and I'll just format everything to snake case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Within the `shapiro_test`, there is a line which does `select(!!! syms(...` where it fails because of the additional backquote

Comment: Thanks, in the end I used clean snakecase names and everything works.